# Angular number input: how to change comma og decimal

Tags: angularjs

I've created this directive in Angular:

```
myApp.directive('dfnumber', function () {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModel) {

            ngModel.$parsers.unshift(function (newValue) {
                var floatValue = parseFloat(newValue.replace(",", "."));
                return parseFloat(floatValue.toFixed(2));
            });

            element.on("change", function (e) {
                var floatValue = parseFloat(element.val().replace(",", "."));
                element.val(floatValue);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

It's tasks is to transform input like "12,34" to a valid number "12.24". Both the value in the input field and in the model.

If I use it on a `input[type='text']` it is working as expected:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="number">Text input</label>
    <input dfnumber="" type="input" class="form-control" ng-model="number" />
    Number:{{number}}
</div>
```

But I'm interested in using the `input[type='number']` instead, because of it's min and max properties:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="number">Number input</label>
    <input dfnumber="" type="number" min="0" max="100" class="form-control" ng-model="number2"/>
    Number:{{number2}}
</div>
```

But on this number input it's not working. How can I fix this?

See my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dennismadsen/kL45085b/.

Comment: You don't need a change event handler. You don't need the directive for number inputs. And what do you mean by not working?

Comment: Default number input does not support comma as decimal separator, which is used in some regions (like mine). I need input where comma is used as decimal separator automatically being transformed to decimal separator, instead of having in invalid input field. Have you tested my JSFiddle?

Comment: Yes, I have. And it works both with and without your directive.

Comment: FYI: The supported format depends on the browser. From the specs: _a user agent designed for the French market might display the value with apostrophes between thousands and commas before the decimals, and allow the user to enter a value in that manner, internally converting it to the submission format described above_

Comment: I think you will have to use a custom validation directive which IMHO will be most simple and stable solution than hacking around input field since not all browsers treat it correctly. Anyway you can achieve comma by adding `lang="your_country_code` to input and/or `html` tag but as I said this functionality differs across browsers